# Accidential keystore deletion solutions

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-keystore

I've accidentally deleted my keystore file.
What are my options?
How can I contact with some Goolge Support to maybe remove all previous apk versions, so I can push the app with a new one so there will be no other apk to match against.
Or maybe a way to generate a new keystore that behaves as the original? Any idea could help!
Even some migration to a new app, by notifying the users via email or notif.

PS. I tried to restore the file, but it's a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've accidentally deleted my keystore file. What are my options?

You can get it through alias if you have created while generating your keystore file.

> How can I contact with some Goolge Support to maybe remove all previous apk versions, so I can push the app with a new one so there will be no other apk to match against

- For that you can't update your application through your keystore file (which lost) and you can unpublish your application.

> Or maybe a way to generate a new keystore that behaves as the original?

No. While you generate a new keystore file then you need to publish your older application with new package name and with new version using your new keystore file. Before you publish your application with new keystore and new package name then don't need to unpublish your application if you don't want. But yes user will not get any update from older version application.